# Over-ride rownames renaming of duplicates with xtable

Tags: r, xtable

I would like xtable to NOT over-ride my duplicated rowname entries. Consider the following MWE:

```
> require(xtable)
> foo <- matrix(0, 2,2)
> rownames(foo) = rep("bar", 2)
> foo
    [,1] [,2]
bar    0    0
bar    0    0
> xtable(foo)
% latex table generated in R 2.15.0 by xtable 1.7-0 package
% Fri Jun 22 13:59:36 2012
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{rrr}
  \hline
 & 1 & 2 \\ 
  \hline
1 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  2 & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
Warning message:
In data.row.names(row.names, rowsi, i) :
  some row.names duplicated: 2 --> row.names NOT used
```

Instead of having the rownames be 1 and 2, I want them to be my original "bar" and "bar". Is there a way to over-ride xtable's duplicate replacement scheme?

Comment: It isnt xtable. Run `data.frame(foo)`. Use a dataframe, add the row names as the first column, and tell xtable to suppress the real row names.

Comment: That's a creative solution! Please submit that as an answer, since it did the trick.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the **xtable** solution (in a very compact form):

```
> print(xtable(data.frame(row = rownames(foo),data.frame(foo))),include.rownames = FALSE)
% latex table generated in R 2.14.2 by xtable 1.6-0 package
% Fri Jun 22 14:24:59 2012
\begin{table}[ht]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lrr}
  \hline
row & X1 & X2 \\ 
  \hline
bar & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
  bar & 0.00 & 0.00 \\ 
   \hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

This will still kick a warning, and it will be difficult to get your column headings right. The other option is to use `latex` from the **Hmisc** package, which is quite a bit more flexible (but also more complicated; you can turn off the multicolumn stuff):

```
library(Hmisc)
> latex(foo,file = "")
% latex.default(foo, file = "") 
%
\begin{table}[!tbp]
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{lrr}
\hline\hline
\multicolumn{1}{l}{foo}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}&\multicolumn{1}{c}{}\tabularnewline
\hline
bar&$0$&$0$\tabularnewline
bar&$0$&$0$\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{table}
```

Sorry for the terse comment. I was holding a baby at the time.

Comment: Your first suggestion, using a data.frame and a column of row names gives me the desired result. No apologies needed on the comment--it provided enough of a hint to get me a desirable outcome!